# How does one show that the directional derivative of a function is independent of the curve that it's parameterised by?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

How does one prove that the directional derivative of a function,  $f:M\rightarrow{R}$ is independent of the curve it is parameterised by?

Is it something like the following: given two curves $\gamma_{1} :(a, b) \rightarrow M$ and $\gamma_{2} :(c, d) \rightarrow M$ and a chart $\phi :U\subset M\rightarrow\mathbb{R} ^{n} $,  then if $(\phi\circ\gamma_{1})'(0)=(\phi\circ\gamma_{2})'(0)$, where $\gamma_{1}(0)=p=\gamma_{2}(0)$, $p\in U\subset M$,  then $\frac{d} {dt} (f\circ\gamma_{1})(t)\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\frac{d} {ds} (f\circ\gamma_{2})(s)\bigg\vert_{s=0}$?!

Comment: Do you mean that the directional derivative $D_\mathbf{u}f(\mathbf{x_1}(t_1))=D_\mathbf{u}f(\mathbf{x_2}(t_2))$ for any two parametric curves $\mathbf{x_i}(t)$ and some $t_i$? The directional derivative depends on the point you evaluate it at. So you will be plugging in two different $t$ values into the parametrizations. I don't know if this helps at all, but intuitively, I don't see how a directional derivative could depend on a parametrization.

Comment: It's the chain rule, pure and simple.

Comment: That's what I thought, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\gamma_{1})(t)\bigg\vert_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}(f\circ\phi^{-1})((\phi\circ\gamma_{1})(t))\bigg\vert_{t=0}$ $=(f\circ\phi^{-1})'(\phi\circ\gamma_{1}(0))(\phi\circ\gamma_{1})'(0) =(f\circ\phi^{-1})'(\phi\circ\gamma_{2}(0))(\phi\circ\gamma_{2})'(0)$ $=\frac{d}{ds}(f\circ\phi^{-1})((\phi\circ\gamma_{1})(s))\bigg\vert_{s=0}=\frac{d}{ds}(f\circ\gamma_{2})(s)\bigg\vert_{s=0}$. Would this be correct?